# Visual Studio BI tool error

Tags: sql-server, web-services, ssl, ssis, wsdl

Good Day!

When you download in Web Service Task a WSDLfile - error

> "SSL certificate response obtained from the server was not valid.
>   Cannot process the request."

What could be problem?

Visual Studio version 2013

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the SSL certificate on the server is not valid. This is probably because it's a temporary certificate, or you self-signed it.

Add the signer of the temporary certificate to the trusted authorities list on the computer running the package.

Or import the temporary certificate as a trusted certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the lack of support for Cryptographic Protocols of the SSIS Web Service Task. A better approach would be to rewrite it as an SSIS Script Task with the help of the  WSDL.exe Tool and then including the generated file (.cs) into your Script Task project.

The wsdl tool is available via the Visual Studio Command prompt (under visual studio/tools in the start menu):

```
wsdl /language:CS /out:<>C# path file> <WSDL file path>
```

Then copy-paste the Generated C# class into the Solution Explorer tree for the SSIS Script Task Project while editing.

Finally, enable the TLS Protocol in the class constructor according the .NET Version as showed on https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/.